# Unitary evolution of quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

In QM the unitary operator is everywhere and alway given $\hat U = e^{- i \hat H t/\hbar}$ so that a system evolves unitarily so that $\hat U |\psi(t_0) \rangle = |\psi(t) \rangle$ at another time $t$.
Our lecturer did not show why the quantum system evolves with this exponential. How is this shown?

Comment: I presume you mean $\exp(-i\hat H t/\hbar)$ and not $\exp(-iH(t)/\hbar)$.  For one, if the Hamiltonian is time dependent then $U$ is NOT of the form you suggest.

Comment: yes. i fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also a fact that the state $\psi (t)$ also changes according to the Schrodinger equation. That is,

$$ i\hbar \frac{d}{d t}|\psi(t)\rangle = \hat H |\psi(t)\rangle$$

Given that the state $|\psi(t)\rangle = \hat U |\psi(t_0) \rangle$ we can then write

$$ i\hbar \frac{d }{d t}\hat U |\psi(t_0)\rangle =    \hat H \hat U |\psi(t_0)\rangle $$

$$\rightarrow  i\hbar \frac{d }{d t}\hat U  =  \hat H \hat U$$

The solution to this equation (and it is important to note here that $H$ does not depend on time)

$$\large i\hbar \frac{d }{d t}\hat U  =  \hat H \hat U$$

is of course the exponential function so that

$$\hat U = \large e^{ \large \frac{- i \hat H t}{\hbar}}$$